# Selecting columns with range of values in R

Tags: r, select, range

I have a dataset as follows

```
date    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N
2001    2   3   5   9   2   24  50  2   11  37  9   2   24  50
2002    3   14  14  5   2   21  28  3   14  14  2   3   2   8
2003    0   12  2   3   4   29  30  0   12  2   3   4   3   30
2004    1   3   3   2   2   1   4   1   3   3   2   2   1   4
2005    0   0   2   0   2   1   1   0   0   2   0   2   1   1
2006    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2007    0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
2008    0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0
2009    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
2010    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

from this set I want to select only those columns which as at least one value greater than 20. My desired set is as follows

```
date    F   G   J   M   N
2001    24  50  37  24  50
2002    21  28  14  2   8
2003    29  30  2   3   30
2004    1   4   3   1   4
2005    1   1   2   1   1
2006    0   0   0   0   0
2007    1   0   0   1   0
2008    0   0   1   0   0
2009    0   0   0   0   0
2010    1   0   0   1   0
```

I tried using

```
mydf<-mydf[,apply(mydf,2,function(z) any(z>20))]
```

but I'm not getting the result. I have dataset containing more than 500 columns.

How can I filter columns with specific range of values?

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you certain your columns are all numeric? Try `sapply(mydf, class)` to see if you have any factors or strings.

Comment: actually my first column "date" is factor. The actual format of date is "31/12/2001".

Comment: Perhaps you need `mydf[-1] <- apply(mydf[-1], 2, ...)` instead, preserving the first column. If all other columns are numeric or integer, though, your code works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a slightly safer version if you want to keep the non-numeric columns:

```
mydf[, sapply(mydf, function(col) !is.numeric(col) || any(col >= 20)), drop = FALSE]
```

And if you really want just the numerics:

```
mydf[, sapply(mydf, function(col) is.numeric(col) && any(col >= 20)), drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

here are some solutions using tidyverse, with `select_if` function and other methods

```r
df <- data.frame(
  date = c(2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L,
           2010L),
  A = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  B = c(3L, 14L, 12L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  C = c(5L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  D = c(9L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
  E = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  F = c(24L, 21L, 29L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
  G = c(50L, 28L, 30L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  H = c(2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  I = c(11L, 14L, 12L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  J = c(37L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  K = c(9L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
  L = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  M = c(24L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
  N = c(50L, 8L, 30L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)


# using tidyverse
library(tidyverse)
# as date is > 20L, it is kept
df %>% 
  select_if(~ any(.x > 20))
#>    date  F  G  J  M  N
#> 1  2001 24 50 37 24 50
#> 2  2002 21 28 14  2  8
#> 3  2003 29 30  2  3 30
#> 4  2004  1  4  3  1  4
#> 5  2005  1  1  2  1  1
#> 6  2006  0  0  0  0  0
#> 7  2007  1  0  0  1  0
#> 8  2008  0  0  1  0  0
#> 9  2009  0  0  0  0  0
#> 10 2010  1  0  0  1  0

# in two step
bind_cols(
  df %>% select(date),
  df %>% select(-date) %>%
    select_if(~ any(.x > 20))
)
#>    date  F  G  J  M  N
#> 1  2001 24 50 37 24 50
#> 2  2002 21 28 14  2  8
#> 3  2003 29 30  2  3 30
#> 4  2004  1  4  3  1  4
#> 5  2005  1  1  2  1  1
#> 6  2006  0  0  0  0  0
#> 7  2007  1  0  0  1  0
#> 8  2008  0  0  1  0  0
#> 9  2009  0  0  0  0  0
#> 10 2010  1  0  0  1  0

# using tidy data by reshaping with one column value
df %>%
  gather("letters", "value", -date) %>%
  # keep only group that have a value above 20
  group_by(letters) %>%
  mutate(to_keep = any(value > 20)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # filter 
  filter(to_keep) %>%
  select(-to_keep) %>%
  spread(letters, value)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>     date     F     G     J     M     N
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1  2001    24    50    37    24    50
#>  2  2002    21    28    14     2     8
#>  3  2003    29    30     2     3    30
#>  4  2004     1     4     3     1     4
#>  5  2005     1     1     2     1     1
#>  6  2006     0     0     0     0     0
#>  7  2007     1     0     0     1     0
#>  8  2008     0     0     1     0     0
#>  9  2009     0     0     0     0     0
#> 10  2010     1     0     0     1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>