# error could not find function "%>%<-" when assigning NA to values out of a range in a data frame with many columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I want to assign NA to values not within a range [0.0, 3.0].
To do this, I should 1) select the values, and 2) assign NA to the values.

I read a solution using `select_if()` from the link below

[Selecting columns with range of values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804987/selecting-columns-with-range-of-values-in-r)

With the solution, I succeeded to select the values I want.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(100)
df = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100) + 1, ncol = 10))
df %>% select_if(~ all(.x > 0 & .x < 3))
```

But when I assigned NA like below:

```
df %>% select_if(~ all(.x > 0 & .x < 3)) <- NA
```

an error occurred:

> could not find function "%>%<-"

What did I miss?

Comment: With a function like `names`, you can do `names(mtcars)` (by itself) and it provides the list of column names. If you do `names(mtcars) <- c("a",...)`, it assigns names in place of the originals. For this functionality to work, there is actually a function named `names<-` providing the LHS capability. Your use of `magrittr` pipes gets rearranged to actually be `\`%>%\`(df, select_if(...)) <- NA`, so the only way that that would work is if `\`%>%<-\`` was defined (which it is not).

Comment: One problem with trying to actually assign that (using LHS notation) is that the encompassing function (`%>%`) does not immediately know what the nested functions are doing (`select_if` in this case), so replacing *some* of the columns/values is not immediately obvious. It's better (as in Ronak's answer) to be explicit.

Comment: @r2evans I didn't know there is really a function like "names<-". Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select_if` is not the correct function here, moreover read the comment from @r2evan's to understand why it actually doesn't work.

Try using `mutate_all` with `replace` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>%  mutate_all(funs(replace(., . > 0 & . < 3, NA)))
```

---

Same with base R, you could try

```
df[df > 0 & df < 3] <- NA
```

Comment: It's right the base R method works as well. I used select_if() to avoid specifying many columns manually in [].